# Spark DataFrame add "[" character per record

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I'm doing this:

```
val xmlDataRDD : RDD[String] = anyDataFrame.get.select("columnSelected")
```

any data in the RDD (xmlDataRDD) is stored in this form:

```
[valueofColumnSelected]
[valueofColumnSelected]
[valueofColumnSelected]
[valueofColumnSelected]
```

Do you know how can I avoid the "[" and "]" in the records? I don't want to execute a replace line to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is due to converting dataframe to RDD could result a Row with square bracket [] in all row elements.

you can use the below approach to retrieve the actual value from each row using RDD builtin functions.

```
someDF.select("number").show()
/*
+---------+
|number   |
+---------+
|     8   |
|    64   |
|   -27   |
+---------+ */

someDF.select("number").rdd.collect()

/* Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([8], [64], [-27]) */ 

someDF.select("number").rdd.collect().foreach {row => println(row(0).toString.toInt)}
/* 
8
64
-27*/
```